# Convert number to a padded string in crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports for reporting. I have a small problem, actually I have a field call `{id}` on my report that is bound to an identity of my sql table. It shows values like **1,2,3,4** but I want my values to be padded with zeros on left to make it 7 digits in all. Ex- **0000001,0000002,0000003,0000004, and for 1234 it should be 0001234**.

I tried `Right("0000"&{MyFieldToPad},7)` but its not working, it says it need boolean!

Comment: MyFieldToPad.ToString("0000000")

Comment: Sorry, where do I put that code?

Comment: Where it needs to stay in your whole code :P

Comment: The field is not on my webpage! Its on a report!

Comment: if you have an int variable, say `int i = 1` if you call ToString() with a format like "00" you'll get back "01"

Comment: does the report support C# code?

Comment: I know that, thanks, but I cannot access a crystal report variable that way in c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If {table.id} is numeric, you need to use the `totext()` function to specify the format and convert it to a string: `totext({table.id},"0000000")`

If {table.id} is a varchar, then your sample formula should work: `right("0000000"&{table.id},7)` No idea why it would say you need a boolean... My guess is that you're not creating a new formula like you should be and instead putting that code where it doesn't belong. Try creating a new formula from scratch with just that code.

Comment: My variable {id} is of number type, may  be thats why its not working.

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL query instead of saying

```
SELECT id 
  --, other columns
  FROM dbo.table
  WHERE ...
;
```

Say:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), id), 7)
  --, other columns
  FROM dbo.table
  WHERE ...
;
```

Comment: it is giving -1 for all cases.

Comment: Well perhaps it is your report or crystal reports code. Did you try running that query directly against SQL Server?